# How to include relative script source file bashrc

Tags: linux, bash

I have multiple bash file. 
I want to write a master bash file which will include all required bash file in current directory.
I tried like this

```
#!/bin/bash
HELPER_DIR=`dirname $0`
.$HELPER_DIR/alias
```

But I when I put following line in my 
$HOME/.bashrc

```
if [ -f /home/vivek/Helpers/bash/main.bash ]; then
    . /home/vivek/Helpers/bash/main.bash
fi
```

I am getting error no such file ./alias. File alias is there. How can I include relative bash file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )` instead.

I added these two lines two my `~/.bashrc`:

```
echo '$0=' $0
echo '$BASH_SOURCE[0]=' ${BASH_SOURCE[0]}
```

and started bash:

```
$ bash
$0= bash
$BASH_SOURCE[0]= /home/igor/.bashrc
```

There is a difference between $0 and $BASH_SOURCE when you start a script with `source` (or `.`) or in `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to leave a space after the "dot"

```
. $HELPER_DIR/alias
```

Answer (score 1):

`$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )` returns `.` if you invoke the script from the same directory or a relative path if you call it using a relative path such as `../myscript.sh`.

I use `script_dir=$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )` to get the directory that the script is in.

Here's an example script to test this functionality:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script is located at /home/lrobert/test.sh

# This just tests the current PWD
echo "PWD: $(pwd)"


# Using just bash source returns the relative path to the script
# If called from /home with the command 'lrobert/test.sh' this returns 'lrobert'
bash_source="$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")"
echo "bash_source: ${bash_source}"


# This returns the actual path to the script
# Returns /home/lrobert when called from any directory
script_dir=$( cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)
echo "script_dir: ${script_dir}"

# This just tests to see if our PWD was modified
echo "PWD: $(pwd)"
```